# Custom circular reveal transition results in "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" when paused?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

I created a custom circular reveal transition to use as part of an Activity's enter transition (specifically, I am setting the transition as the window's enter transition by calling `Window#setEnterTransition()`):

```
public class CircularRevealTransition extends Visibility {
    private final Rect mStartBounds = new Rect();

    /**
     * Use the view's location as the circular reveal's starting position.
     */
    public CircularRevealTransition(View v) {
        int[] loc = new int[2];
        v.getLocationInWindow(loc);
        mStartBounds.set(loc[0], loc[1], loc[0] + v.getWidth(), loc[1] + v.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Animator onAppear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, final View v, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {
        if (endValues == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int halfWidth = v.getWidth() / 2;
        int halfHeight = v.getHeight() / 2;
        float startX = mStartBounds.left + mStartBounds.width() / 2 - halfWidth;
        float startY = mStartBounds.top + mStartBounds.height() / 2 - halfHeight;
        float endX = v.getTranslationX();
        float endY = v.getTranslationY();
        v.setTranslationX(startX);
        v.setTranslationY(startY);

        // Create a circular reveal animator to play behind a shared
        // element during the Activity Transition.
        Animator revealAnimator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, halfWidth, halfHeight, 0f,
                FloatMath.sqrt(halfWidth * halfHeight + halfHeight * halfHeight));
        revealAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // Set the view's visibility to VISIBLE to prevent the
                // reveal from "blinking" at the end of the animation.
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // Translate the circular reveal into place as it animates.
        PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", startX, endX);
        PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationY", startY, endY);
        Animator translationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v, pvhX, pvhY);

        AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
        anim.setInterpolator(getInterpolator());
        anim.playTogether(revealAnimator, translationAnimator);
        return anim;
    }
}
```

This works OK normally. However, when I click the "back button" in the middle of the transition, I get the following exception:

```
Process: com.adp.activity.transitions, PID: 13800
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.pause(RenderNodeAnimator.java:251)
        at android.animation.AnimatorSet.pause(AnimatorSet.java:472)
        at android.transition.Transition.pause(Transition.java:1671)
        at android.transition.TransitionSet.pause(TransitionSet.java:483)
        at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.startExitBackTransition(ActivityTransitionState.java:269)
        at android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition(Activity.java:4672)
        at com.adp.activity.transitions.DetailsActivity.finishAfterTransition(DetailsActivity.java:167)
        at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2480)
```

Is there any specific reason why I am getting this error? How should it be avoided?

Comment: I gave you my point of view explanation on this kind of buggy behaviour on G+!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to create a subclass of `Animator` that ignores calls to `pause()` and `resume()` in order to avoid this exception.

For more details, I just finished a post about this topic below:

- **Part 1:** http://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/reveal-transition/
- **Part 2:** https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/reveal-activity-transitions/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This seems to fix the problem for me. I edited your answer to provide a bit more context for the link.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any specific reason why I am getting this error?

[`ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.java#L48) is a shortcut for creating a new [`RevealAnimator`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/animation/RevealAnimator.java#L29), which is a subclass of `RenderNodeAnimator`. By default, [`RenderNodeAnimator.pause`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/view/RenderNodeAnimator.java#L250) throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You see this occur here in your stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.pause(RenderNodeAnimator.java:251)
```

When `Activity.onBackPressed` is called in Lollipop, it makes a new call to [`Activity.finishAfterTransition`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L4671), which eventually makes a call back to `Animator.pause` in [`Transition.pause(android.view.View)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/transition/Transition.java#L1671), which is when your `UnsupportedOperationException` is finally thrown.

The reason it isn't thrown when using the "back" button after the transition is complete, is due to how the [`EnterTransitionCoordinator` handles the entering `Transition` once it's completed.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/EnterTransitionCoordinator.java#L457)

> How should it be avoided?

I suppose you have a couple of options, but neither are really ideal:

**Option 1**

Attach a [`TransitionListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.TransitionListener.html) when you call `Window.setEnterTransition` so you can monitor when to invoke the "back" button. So, something like:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    /** True if the current window transition is animating, false otherwise */
    private boolean mIsAnimating = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the Window and enable Activity transitions
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        // Call through to super
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

        // Set the window transition and attach our listener
        final Transition circularReveal = new CircularRevealTransition(yourView);
        window.setEnterTransition(circularReveal.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                super.onTransitionEnd(transition);
                mIsAnimating = false;
            }

        }));

        // Restore the transition state if available
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsAnimating = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("key");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save the current transition state
        outState.putBoolean("key", mIsAnimating);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!mIsAnimating) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

**Option 2**

Use reflection to call [`ActivityTransitionState.clear`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionState.java#L237), which will stop `Transition.pause(android.view.View)` from being called in [`ActivityTransitionState.startExitBackTransition`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionState.java#L255).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mIsAnimating) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        clearTransitionState();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private void clearTransitionState() {
    try {
        // Get the ActivityTransitionState Field
        final Field atsf = Activity.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityTransitionState");
        atsf.setAccessible(true);
        // Get the ActivityTransitionState
        final Object ats = atsf.get(this);
        // Invoke the ActivityTransitionState.clear Method
        final Method clear = ats.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clear", (Class[]) null);
        clear.invoke(ats);
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Obviously each has drawbacks. Option 1 basically disables the "back" button until the transition is complete. Option 2 allows you to interrupt using the "back" button, but clears the transition state and uses reflection.

[Here's a gfy of the results.](http://www.gfycat.com/ThoroughDeterminedAsiaticwildass#?speed=3) You can see how it completely transitions from "A" to "M" and back again, then the "back" button interrupts the transition and goes back to "A". That'll make more sense if you watch it.

At any rate, I hope that helps you out some.

Comment: Both approaches definitely feel hacky. If I had to choose between the two I would probably prefer the first over the second since the reflection seems kind of scary. Who knows what the side effects of clearing the transition's state might be...

Comment: Perhaps there is another way... if all you want to do is prevent `Animator#pause()` from being called, maybe you could just wrap the circular reveal animator in a simple `Animator` wrapper subclass that forwards all of its method calls _except_ `pause()` to the circular reveal animator. Seems a little safer than using reflection, at least... but still doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Yeah, that seems much nicer, but still not ideal. Either way, pretty sure you're throwing the `Exception` because the `Animator` eventually makes its way back to `RenderNodeAnimator.pause`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener to enter transition that sets flag `transitionInProgress` in methods `onTransitionStart()` / `onTransitionEnd()`. Then, you can override method `finishAfterTransition()` and then check `transitionInProgress` flag, and call `super` only if transition finished. Otherwise you can just `finish()` your `Activity` or do nothing.

```
override fun finishAfterTransition() {
    if (!transitionInProgress){
        super.finishAfterTransition()
    } else {
        finish()
    }
}
```